# subprocess.Popen() write stdout to logfile

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am using the following command to redirect `ffmpeg` output to terminal and text file.

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen (['ffmpeg', 'some_ffmpeg_command', '-f', 'mpegts', 'outfile.ts'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
for line in p1.stdout:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    logfile.write(line)
p1.stdout.close()
p1.wait()
```

The code works fine until a scenario where manual intervention is required. For example, if the file outfile.ts already exists, then the following dialogue is not displayed in console,
`File 'Desktop/mytestfolder/outfile.ts' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]`

Any idea what's wrong with the above please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `-y` flag to force a yes response since you can't rely on user interaction.

Comment: sure, I can do that. But I don't want as this scenario is just an example and I would like to have it displayed on terminal rather than forcing yes for everything.

Answer (score 0):

problem is that this prompt doesn't end with a `\n` so python read line method waits for it before fetching the whole line.

The workaround is to read the input character by character. For instance like this:

```
current_line = []
while True:
   c = p1.stdout.read(1).decode()
   if not c:
      break
   current_line.append(c)
   # here you can test if the last character is "]" to avoid creating a partial line everytime
   if c == ']':
      partial_line = ''.join(current_line)
      if partial_line.endswith("Overwrite ? [y/N]"):
         # do something, for instance, print it
         print("PROMPT: {}\n".format(partial_line))
   elif c == '\n':
      # full line: print it
      line = ''.join(current_line)
      # reset the current line buffer
      current_line = []
      # and write the line
      sys.stdout.write(line)
      logfile.write(line)
```

Of course, without answering, the process is going to be blocked. So `Popen` needs `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` too, so you can use `p1.stdin.write("Y\n")` to reply to the prompt, (or `"N\n"` depending on the question).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `y` into STDIN.

**Solution with Popen:**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

foo_proc = Popen(['foo', 'bar'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
yes_proc = Popen(['y'], stdout=foo_proc.stdin)
foo_output = foo_proc.communicate()[0]
yes_proc.wait()
```

**Solution with STDIN writing:**

```
foo_proc = Popen(['foo', 'bar'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
sp.stdin.write("y\n")  # "\n" is important!
foo_output = foo_proc.communicate()[0]
yes_proc.wait()
```